# Track referrals from the definition phase into the commitment phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51, referrals

If a user that was referred in the definition phase commits to the proposal, it should count as a user that committed directly without following (giving you the +25 when he fulfills his commitment).

Does it work like this now?
If not, I feature-request it

Comment: -1: I question your motives in posting this, seeing as how you're using your position as a moderator at Gaming to currently push Gaming Recommendations in Gaming's Meta using a referral link.

Comment: +1 I don't care about the rep, but if you refer someone (s)he was referred by you. Period. @Powerlord: referring people is what that link is for... And he also added a *disclaimer* about that fact. It's not like Juan's spamming answers where that proposal is irrelevant, anyway

Comment: Adding to what @Tobias said: no one is abusing anything, you can post your referral links in the same fashion if you want (I mean, without spamming or anything like that); also, all you'd gain is area51 reputation which everyone says it's useless anyway. The request is meant for consistency only.

Comment: @Tobias: That disclaimer was added after I flagged said post for moderator attention on Gaming Meta (yes, I was the one who flagged it Juan, which shouldn't surprise you in the least).

Comment: @Powerlord, flags for mod attention are not anonymous.

Comment: @Powerlord, I *honestly* did forget to put it, and I forgot because it's really not that important -- if it really offends you, flag the post again and I will remove it; I'd love to do anything in my power to make your experience at Gaming.SE the best possible.